# I haven't participated in the current arena season, will I be able to gain my Conquest Points in the next one?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I just came back from a long break (I left in 5.1). I just logged in and I can get 25k conquest points this week. I am wondering if, when the new patch (and season) arrives, will I still have that available, or I'll start at the normal rate per week?

This is because I want to hold on to that cap when the new season arrives. But should I get my gear now?

Answer (score 1):

The cap resets with new season starting, what you are seeing is a catch-up method for 5.3.

It is calculated like this:

> (Current week of the season) * 1000 – (Conquest earned thus far this
>   season)

So based on your 25k conquest cap I would say you are 25 weeks into the season

> 25 * 1000 - 0